# SwiftUI AVPlayer Status .readyToPlay

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, avplayer

I need to show a poster image and wait for the video status to become .readyToPlay to actually play the video. Below is my code that doesn't work, I guess the status is false at the rendering time, how to bind an observer?

```
@State private var videoReady: Bool = false

var body: some View {

let player = AVPlayer(url: game.video!)
    
    GeometryReader { proxy in
        WebImage(
            url: app.sanityClient.imageURL(game.poster).URL()
        )
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(self.ratio, contentMode: .fill)
            .onAppear(){
                //  i check the status here
                self.videoReady = player.status == .readyToPlay
            }
        
        if self.videoReady {
            VideoPlayer(player: player)
                .onDisappear {
                    player.pause()
                }
                .onAppear(){
                    player.play()
                    player.isMuted = true
                }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Try to make to a ["minimal, reproducible example" (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help others  help you with your code.